# Set and Logic, Proving two quantifier the same

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

$(∃x∈A:P(x))∨(∃x∈B:P(x)) = ∃x∈(A∪B):P(x)$

I spent hours approaching this problem many different way

By Definition:
$(∃x∈A:P(x))∨(∃x∈B:P(x))
\\ ∃x:[(x∈A \to P(x) \vee (x∈B \to P(x)]
\\ ∃x:[(¬x∈A ∨ P(x) \vee (¬x∈B ∨ P(x)]
\\ ∃x:[¬x∈A ∨ P(x) \vee ¬x∈B ∨ P(x)]
\\ ∃x:[(¬x∈A ∨ ¬x∈B) ∨ P(x)]
\\ ∃x:[¬(x∈ A\cap B) ∨ P(x)]
\\ ∃x:[(x∈ A\cap B)\to P(x)]
\\ ∃x∈(A\cap B):P(x)]
\qquad\qquad \neq ∃x∈A∪B:P(x)$

COULD Someone tell me what is wrong with this logic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bit:  $\exists x\in A\big( P(x) \big) \neq \exists x \big(x \in A \to P(x)\big)$.

For a restriction existential quantification we use the conjunction, not the implication.  That's for the restricted universal quantification.

$$\exists x\in A\big( P(x) \big) = \exists x \big(x \in A \wedge P(x)\big)$$

---

So your proof should look like:

$$\begin{align}& (\exists x\in A:P(x))\vee(\exists x\in B:P(x))
\\[1ex]\Updownarrow & \text{(restricted existential)}
\\[1ex] & \exists x:[(x\in A \wedge P(x))] \vee \exists x:[(x\in B \wedge P(x))]
\\[1ex]\Updownarrow & \text{(disjunction of existential quantification)}
\\[1ex] & \exists x:[(x\in A \wedge P(x)) \vee (x\in B \wedge P(x))]
\\[1ex]\Updownarrow & \text{(distribution)}
\\[1ex] & \exists x:[(x\in A \vee x\in B) \wedge P(x)]
\\[1ex]\Updownarrow & \text{(definition of set union)}
\\[1ex] & \exists x:[(x\in (A \cup B)) \wedge P(x)]
\\[1ex]\Updownarrow & \text{(restricted existential)}
\\[1ex] & \exists x\in (A\cup B):P(x)
\end{align}$$